# Setting the each log stream size of lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

Lambda makes the log streams automatically,

However I wonder why each log stream are short.

I need to move the log from cloudwatch to S3 and download.

when files are separated so I need to download them many times manually.
(I can't use ftp or aws-cli)

Is there anyt way to set the size of each log streams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change that. But the easiest way to send CW logs to S3 is through [CloudWatch Logs subscription filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html). In your case you could setup:

```
CW Logs ---> Firehose ---> S3
```

Comment: I see, I understood I wii try to learn `Firehose` for now.